# maui: changing a bound string from code does not update ui unless string is regenerated (mvvm)

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

This is my string:

```cs
public string EmptyViewText { get; set; } = "Please input a bin id first!*";
```

I have a simple command:

```cs
public async Task Entry(string barcode)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        EmptyViewText = "Loading data...*";
        OnPropertyChanged();
    });
}
```

This is triggered.

This is my class:

```cs
public partial class BinViewModel : ObservableObject
```

The binding itself works, as I do see my values. But when I change the values from code, nothing happens.

The binding is super simple:

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding EmptyViewText}"  />
```

If I however disable the string and reenable it (re render it) it does show up with the new and correted text.

What is of issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is calling `OnPropertyChanged()` without an argument. Wherever that method is, it's probably defined similar to this:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The caller in this case is `Entry` not `EmptyViewText`. It's going to fire a property changed event, but on the wrong property.

See if it makes a difference if you call it with an explicit argument:

```
public async Task Entry(string barcode)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        EmptyViewText = "Loading data...*";
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EmptyViewText));
    });
}
```

Comment: my guy, easy fix and totally working! comming from blazor there is just a call to "bindingChanged" neede, but its different here i see, thank you!

Comment: That's the quick fix :)

Answer (score 2):

A clean fix would be to change this

```cs
public partial class BinViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string EmptyViewText { get; set; } = "Please input a bin id first!*";
}
```

to this

```cs
public partial class BinViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string emptyViewText = "Please input a bin id first!*";
}
```

and this

```cs
public async Task Entry(string barcode)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        EmptyViewText = "Loading data...*";
        OnPropertyChanged();
    });
}
```

to

```cs
public async Task Entry(string barcode)
{
    EmptyViewText = "Loading data...*";

    //... whatever else you need to do (asynchronously)
}
```

It shouldn't be necessary to wrap the property assignment in a call to the `MainThread` as property bindings are updated on the main thread anyway.

Comment: Also very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#simple-property).  When using `ObservableObject` you need to implement `SetProperty` in the setter, or use `[ObservableProperty]`

```
public class User : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
}
```